# Addlegendentry doesn't show properly the color in the legend of the plot PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\pgfplotsset{
  Cus/.style={
        axis equal image,
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
    \begin{axis}[
        Cus,
        xmin=-2.1, xmax=4.1,
        legend pos=outer north east,
        legend cell align={left}
        ]
        \addplot[very thick,blue,samples=300,domain=1:4.1] {sqrt((x-1)/2)};
        \addplot[very thick,blue,samples=300,domain=1:4.1] {-sqrt((x-1)/2)};
        \addlegendentry{$x-2y^2=1$}
        \addplot[very thick,red,samples=300,domain=1:4.1] {sqrt(x-1)};
        \addplot[very thick,red,samples=300,domain=1:4.1] {-sqrt(x-1)};
        \addlegendentry{$x-y^2=1$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Color legend]

I am doing something wrong? How can I make the second legend have the corresponding color (red)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you've added four plots but only two legend entries. These entries correspond to the first two plots, both of which are blue. Try adding another legend entry; it will be red.

An easy way to fix this is draw both upper portions with `\addlegendentry`, then draw both lower portions without `\addlegendentry`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\pgfplotsset{
  Cus/.style={
        axis equal image,
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
    \begin{axis}[
        Cus,
        xmin=-2.1, xmax=4.1,
        legend pos=outer north east,
        legend cell align={left}
        ]
        \addplot[very thick,blue,samples=300,domain=1:4.1] {-sqrt((x-1)/2)};
        \addlegendentry{$x-2y^2=1$}
        \addplot[very thick,red,samples=300,domain=1:4.1] {-sqrt(x-1)};
        \addlegendentry{$x-y^2=1$}
        \addplot[very thick,blue,samples=300,domain=1:4.1] {sqrt((x-1)/2)};
        \addplot[very thick,red,samples=300,domain=1:4.1] {sqrt(x-1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I ask you a quick question here, please? It's about creating the blue curve of the graph; if I do not specify the domain (`1:4.1`) it does not finish arriving at the `x`-axis. It happens with the positive and negative branches. It also happens to me if I want to make an ellipse with the following code: `\addplot [very thick, gray, samples=300, domain=0:3] {sqrt(2)*sqrt(2*x-x^2)};` (with or without domain is the same). How can I make both curves touch the `x`-axis? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps using parametric equations, but if possible without modifying the type of equation, just "complete" the part of the missing graph (which is not much).

Comment: @manooooh I think Stefan Pinnow's answer addresses your question (and is probably a better answer than mine.)

Comment: @erik you've just answered a long time interrogation on legends :) merci.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid to add "dummy" legend entries you could either use `forget plot` or -- in your given example -- draw the plots in a parametric way in one go.

For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        Cus/.style={
            axis equal image,
            axis lines=center,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        Cus,
        xmin=-2.1,
        xmax=4.1,
        legend pos=outer north east,
        legend cell align={left},
        ticks=none,
        % moved common `\addplot' options here
        no markers,
        smooth,
        domain=1:4.1,
        samples=101,
        every axis plot/.append style={
            very thick,
        },
    ]
        % either add `forget plot' to each first plot half, which avoids
        % increasing the `cycle list' and avoids counting for the legend ...
        \addplot+ [forget plot] {sqrt((x-1)/2)};
        \addplot                {-sqrt((x-1)/2)};
            \addlegendentry{$x-2y^2=1$}
%        \addplot+ [forget plot] {sqrt(x-1)};
%        \addplot                {-sqrt(x-1)};
        % ... or draw the lines as parametric plots which doesn't need that
        % much `samples' and can be drawn in one go
        \addplot+ [domain=-2:2,samples=25] (x^2 + 1,x);
            \addlegendentry{$x-y^2=1$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]